# How to retrieve only elements that are not nested?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to parse some XML content, in this case with some products:

```
<PRODUCTS>
  <PRODUCT>
    <NAME><![CDATA[Some name]]></NAME>
    <CATEGORIES>
      <CATEGORY>
        <NAME><![CDATA[Category 1]]></NAME>
      </CATEGORY>
      <CATEGORY>
        <NAME><![CDATA[Category 2]]></NAME>
      </CATEGORY>
    </CATEGORIES>
  </PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCT>
    <NAME><![CDATA[Some other name]]></NAME>
    <CATEGORIES>
      <CATEGORY>
        <NAME><![CDATA[Category 1]]></NAME>
      </CATEGORY>
      <CATEGORY>
        <NAME><![CDATA[Category 2]]></NAME>
      </CATEGORY>
    </CATEGORIES>
  </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTS>
```

If I put the above into a `doc` variable and call for the `NAME` in each product:

```
doc.css("PRODUCT").each do |product|
  puts product.css("NAME").size # => 3
end
```

I also get the nested `NAME` elements of each product.

How do I get only the `NAME` that is not nested? I know that `product.at_css("NAME")` returns only the first element, but my question is not how to get the first element, but rather how to get elements that are not nested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `>` to select only `NAME` elements that are direct children of `PRODUCT`:

```
doc.css("PRODUCT").each do |product|
  puts product.css("> NAME")
end
```

This will output the following:

```
<NAME><![CDATA[Some name]]></NAME>
<NAME><![CDATA[Some other name]]></NAME>
```

Comment: Thanks but this would completely change the order in which things are done. It would limit an operation to only work with one kind of element. If I wanted to do a series of tasks product by product I couldn't use this approach, because in this approach things are done element name by element name.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 Look at the updated version. My original example was on the terse side, of course you don't have to use the combined selector right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
doc.css("PRODUCT").each do |product|
   puts product.css("NAME").first
end
```

Comment: This is dependent on the order of the XML though. If `CATEGORIES` and `NAME` ever get switched, it would return the first category's name.

Comment: Absolutely, your answer is way better !

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly what I mentioned that I wasn't looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
doc.xpath("PRODUCTS/PRODUCT").each do |product| 
  puts product.xpath("NAME").first
end
```

`.xpath("NAME")` in this case returns only immediate descendants. Same effect can be achieved with css child selector.

```
doc.css("PRODUCT").each do |product| 
  puts product.css("> NAME").first
end
```